# Proper API caching with nginx

Tags: caching, nginx

I'm serving a website with nginx. The site is all static files, with the exception of `/api` being proxied to my API process internally. I'm running some site speed tests, and I keep getting results saying `/api/<whatever>` needs cache control. Specifically:

> The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources: ...

and

> The following resources are missing a cache validator. Resources that do not specify a cache validator cannot be refreshed efficiently. Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for the following resources: ...

My server isn't returning any caching information whatsoever for the API--I don't want the API cached. Both `ETag` and `Last-Modified` are sent for the resources that actually are static.

What's the proper way to handle this with nginx? What do I need to enable or disable to set the API to never be cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 add_header "Cache-Control" "private,nocache";
```

Comment: That was way easier than I was expecting. -_- Thank you!